# Always getting nopreview message displayed in my url?

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-template

So, I am  working on a shopify platform, the problem I am having is a problem that I am not sure really if it is because of some code I added or not! So what is happening is that when I go to my main page ( **domainname.com** ), my url is changing to '**domainname.com/*?nopreview***', and this is causing me problems because I have things that I have in my main page and I dont want to see them in product page, so to do so I added a JS code :

```
if(window.location.hostname === window.location.href){
    // here code to add some DOM elements
}else {
    // here code to add or remove some DOM elements
}
```

One of the reasons I dont think it is a code problem is that I have this problem only on one computer, but everything looks fine on the others!

So what do you think ? and can such problem be solved using some extra code ?

**Note:** When I refresh the page and remove that extra in url, it returns!

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to get query parameters using the liquid. and DOM elements are loaded first then your js will get executed that is why your current code is not working. however, there is a tricky way to get the current URL parameter.

You can follow the below code hosted on GitHub.

https://github.com/freakdesign/Shopify-code-snippets/tree/master/Get%20querystring%20in%20Shopify%20Liquid

Using the above code on your project you will get **pageUrl** liquid variable which will contain the current page URL with query parameters.

you can compare it with below liquid variable.

```
{{ request.host }}
```

This is possible using this tricky way which might not be reliable and encouraging me to suggest you not to use in production mode.